# How many recursive calls are made when quicksort is size n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, sorting

How many recursive calls are necessary when quickSort sorts an array of size n if you use median-of-three pivot selection?

I thought the answer is n times because isnt this the best case?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Quick sort runs in O($n^2$). Algorithms are analyzed based on worst case performance.

Comment: @JamieLannister is that the time it runs in or the calls it makes?

Comment: The question asks "how many calls". The wording of the question is poor because we don't want what is **necessary** but what is the worst number **possible**.

Comment: Each call is a complexity step it takes. Quick sort makes n calls to a process that runs in $\theta$(n). Therefore, I guess there are n recursive calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median-of-three heuristic does not guarantee the best case at all. In fact, it does not even avoid the worst case behavior, still $O(N^2)$ comparisons.

But whatever the case and the choice strategy for the pivot, processing must continue until the initial array has been partitioned in chunks of constant size, and this always takes $O(N)$ recursive calls.

Also note that when the "smallest first" strategy is used, the recursion depth cannot exceed $O(Log(N))$, whereas without care, it can remains a very bad $O(N)$.